# Abuse complaint regarding my server

Tags: vps

I received this email for my hosting:

> Please see the forwarded e-mail below for more details. Apparently,
> your server is used for hacking which is strictly forbidden by our
> ToS.
>
> ````
> > 167. - [09/Oct/2020:15:37:42 +0200] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10581 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0)
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0" ```
> ````

I then used `chmod 755` for all directories and changed the password for root. Is it solved?

Comment: Is ***what*** solved? Did you use your server for hacking? Are you trying to avoid detection of your hacking activities? Do you suspect that someone hacked your server? What are you trying to solve? What's the server used for? What services are on it? What other user accounts are there, and have you changed those passwords, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then used chmod 755 for all directories and changed the password for root. Is it solved?

No, it's not. If your box is compromised, this will likely not help at all. The first action any attacker will do is to install tools to ensure access.

You have to reinstall it from scratch, and secure it better this time. How to secure it depends on what software you have.

Comment: yes, i will. I detect a website infect,